# I've just started the Javascript and i've had some issue

Tags: javascript

I've just started the Javascript and i've had some issue. So who can explain for me what is happening is this code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p>JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.</p>

<p>In this case JavaScript changes the value of the src (source) attribute of an image.</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Question:** In the code, Have they inserted one image or have they added two picture in this code? Because when i have imposed another photo in this code, and then changed src in this code, I cannot realized the mutation/ variation between the turing on the light and the turning of the light.

Comment: It should be actually changing the image. Maybe the two raw images are literal copies or just very similar?

Answer (score 1):

We start with the first button: `<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>`

Let's break it down `onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'"` changes the image to `pic_bulon.gif` but how?
Well `document.getElementById('myImage')` is doing what it says getting the element(s) with the id `myImage`
Then after that is `.src='pic_bulon.gif'` this sets the attribute `src` to `pic_bulon.gif` aka: on

This is the same with the second button which does the same thing but instead of setting the image to `pic_bulon.gif` it changes it to `pic_buloff.gif` turning it off

Answer (score 0):

Your site will only display one image at a time, what the code does is listen for button clicks that change the source on the img tag